# setOnMouseExited doesn't work with strokes?

Tags: javafx, event-handling, shapes

```
public void frame(Rectangle rechteck) {
        rechteck.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                rechteck.setStroke(Color.DARKGREY);
            }
        });
        rechteck.setOnMouseExited((MouseEvent e) -> {
            rechteck.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        });
    }
```

I try to have a 'hover' effect. I have different rectangles, and I want that when I enter the rectangle it gets a grey stroke. When the cursor leaves the rectangle, the stroke should disappear again.

1. Why is my stroke always grey and doesnt change when I leave the rectangle.
2. How can I disable the stroke? If I exited the rectangle, I dont actually want to change the color to BLUE, but I want that its simply not there anymore.

EDIT: the rest

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        // Die Linie in der Mitte.
        Rectangle line = new Rectangle(0, 0, 450, 1);
        root.getChildren().add(line);

        // Das abgerundete Rechteck.
        Rectangle roundedRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 80);
        roundedRect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        roundedRect.setArcWidth(40);
        roundedRect.setArcHeight(40);
        roundedRect.setFill(Color.BISQUE);
        root.getChildren().add(roundedRect);

        // Die Farblinien.
        Rectangle firstLine = new Rectangle(100, 0, 25, 80);
        firstLine.setFill(Color.BROWN);
        frame(firstLine);
        Rectangle secondLine = new Rectangle(0, 0, 25, 80);
        secondLine.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        frame(secondLine);
        Rectangle thirdLine = new Rectangle(0, 0, 25, 80);
        thirdLine.setFill(Color.RED);
        frame(thirdLine);
        Rectangle fourthLine = new Rectangle(0, 0, 25, 80);
        fourthLine.setFill(Color.GOLD);
        frame(fourthLine);
        HBox lines = new HBox();
        lines.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        lines.setPadding(new Insets(30));
        HBox.setMargin(firstLine, new Insets(0, 30, 0, 0));
        HBox.setMargin(secondLine, new Insets(0, 30, 0, 0));
        HBox.setMargin(thirdLine, new Insets(0, 30, 0, 0));
        HBox.setMargin(fourthLine, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 50));
        lines.getChildren().addAll(firstLine, secondLine, thirdLine, fourthLine);

        double widerstand = (ERSTERRING + ZWEITERRING) * DRITTERRING;

        char groesse = ' ';
        if (widerstand >= 1000 && widerstand < 10000) {
            widerstand = widerstand / 1000;
            groesse = 'k';
        } else if (widerstand >= 1000000) {
            widerstand = widerstand / 1000000;
            groesse = 'M';
        }

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        Text werte = new Text(90, 210, "R = " + widerstand + groesse + "Ω mit " + VIERTERRING + " % Toleranz");
        VBox.setMargin(werte, new Insets(200, 0, 0, 70));
        vbox.getChildren().add(werte);
        root.getChildren().add(vbox);
        root.getChildren().add(lines);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Widerstandsrechner");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is my stroke always grey and doesnt change when I leave the rectangle.

Hard to say without the rest of your code.

> How can I disable the stroke?

Set the stroke to `null` or `Color.TRANSPARENT`.

---

Here is a sample which would seem to accomplish what you want.  First image is without the mouse hovered over the (initially invisible) rectangle.  Second image is with the mouse hovered over the rectangle.

[image: hovered] [image: unhovered]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RectHover extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(
                100, 100, Color.TRANSPARENT
        );

        rectangle.strokeProperty().bind(
                Bindings.when(rectangle.hoverProperty())
                        .then(Color.DARKGREY)
                        .otherwise((Color) null)
        );

        StackPane layout = new StackPane(rectangle);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```